# find number in table with a particular number in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table contain field

```
id-  No  -  point
1 -  10  -  23
2 -  100 -  20
3 -  200 -  30
```

when i search a no like 56.

```
 Output i want.
 only 100
 not 100,200
```

Comment: Post your tried query/code.

Comment: Format your question properly

Comment: This is a simple `SELECT ... WHERE` case. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Why 100, it is not clear? Try [`SELECT No
fROM tablename
WHERE NO > 56 AND point < 56
LIMIT 1`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/620fd/3)

Comment: I do not see, how a number 56 is related to number 100 which you want in the output :) Please try looking at your own post as if you were a new person to the problem, and try to understand it

Comment: Could you please clarify your question! What is your desired output when querying waht specific column.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
select `no` from `table` where `no`>56 limit 1
```

Comment: Escape the 'no'. It's an SQL keyword. Also, case-sensitive.

Comment: @MaximKumpan: yes you are right, but still it works in mysql.

Comment: Seriously? I guess I trust syntax highlighting too much. I also don't like taking semantic risks. Still, vote up from me.

Comment: :) ok am updating the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know for certain as your question is not desperately clear.  I would suggest it looks as straight forward as:

```
SELECT No FROM table WHERE No>$number LIMIT 1
```

If that number is being written in a form, please paramatise your input to protect against SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE No > 56 LIMIT 1
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE No BETWEEN 56 AND 100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from `table_name` where  56 < `No`  order by `no` ASC limit 1
```

check **SQL Fiddle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5af3f/2/0